# How can I see the number of times I earned a badge?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, badges

Title says it all. How can I see the number of times I earned a badge? If I cannot, this would be a good feature to add!

Answer (score 10):

There will be a small "X #" where # is the number of times you've earned the badge.  Check out [Jon Skeet's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).  He's got a few...

[image]

And in your Stack Overflow account, you have multiples of two badges:

[image]

Nice work!!

Comment: oh thank you, I was checking my badges page, when really it was at the bottom of my profile. thanks!

Comment: +1 for `He's got a few...`